# Passport Facebook authentication for website users plus local authentication for admin

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I am creating a website with node and express framework in back end, and angular in front end. I am using passport for authentication. The users of my website can login or signup using only their Facebook ID this is working so far. Now I have to create an admin login. The steps I am going to follow are-

1] Create a separate route which has some secret string at end to get to login
   page. like `localhost:8080/p08jnl`

2] When on this page I have username and password input, where the admin enter 
   the credentials, and would use *passport local authentication* for this.

3] The admin routes can be accessed only after login from the admin portal, I 
   will define a middleware `isAuthenticated()` on those routes.

The thing I am concerned about is, for the routes for users I had defined an `isAuthenticated()` function so that only authenticated users can access those routes.

Would any authenticated user be able to access the routes for admin?

more details on my authentication-
when my website's URL is called

```
'localhost:8080'
```

I send a page which has the Facebook authentication button on it, no angular web app is sent, when user authenticates via Facebook, then the client angular web app is sent.

I am planning to send a page ,when the admin URL is called, with username and password input fields .After successful login, the admin angular web app would be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would any authenticated user be able to access the routes for admin?

Simply create another middleware called **isAdmin**, which checks if that user is an administrator. Then Place the **isAdmin** middleware before any **/admin** routes (or **/p08jnl** routes in your case).